# Xamarin show MenuItem with tap

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, swipe, menuitem

I'm developing cross platform app with Xamarin Forms. I'm wondering if there's an easy way to show MenuItem in a listView with a single tap on a cell.
Now of course, my MenuItem is displayed when user swipes to left, but I would like to show menu when user just tap on a cell. How can I do that?
I tried to translate ViewCell but, even if translation works, nothing appears. 
Have I to make something custom?
Maybe is it possible to "force" a left swipe when user taps on a cell? I tried to find some reference on web and documentation but found nothing

very easy code for MenuItem implementation

```
<ViewCell.ContextActions>
        <MenuItem Text="Delete" Clicked="DeleteElement" x:Name="menuItem"/>
</ViewCell.ContextActions>
```

code for ViewCell translation:

```
await viewCell.View.TranslateTo(-100, 0, 250, Easing.SinIn);
```

Thanks guys

Comment: It is not a good design to open the menu when tap the ViewCell , as listview has tap and click event in default when user select  the ViewCell. Which will maybe cause issue .

Comment: so you think I need something custom without using MenuItem right?

Comment: Yes , you are right :)

Comment: but anyway is it possible to "force" swipe? I mean programmatically call swipe. Just for curiosity! I didn't find any reference

Comment: I'm afraid that you could not implement it in iOS .